# Charting a D3 line chart with an array of objects

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a line chart using D3.js but I am pretty stumped. I've followed [this tutorial](http://www.janwillemtulp.com/2011/04/01/tutorial-line-chart-in-d3/), but I don't see how I can get my data into the chart.

Here's what my data looks like:

```
[
    { name : "SomeKey", timestamp : "2013-05-07T12:00:00.052Z", value : "1" }
    { name : "SomeKey", timestamp : "2013-05-07T12:10:00.052Z", value : "4" }
    { name : "SomeKey", timestamp : "2013-05-07T12:40:00.052Z", value : "2" }
    { name : "SomeKey", timestamp : "2013-05-07T12:41:00.052Z", value : "2" }
    { name : "SomeKey", timestamp : "2013-05-07T12:44:00.052Z", value : "2" }
    ... etc. there can be loads of objects in this array
]
```

As mentioned there can be any number of objects in the array, the `name` key always holds the same value for the array, what I need is the timestamp on the x-axis and the value is what would plot the chart, but I can't quite figure it out.

I looked at a couple of other questions that might be similar to this one on SO, but the difference for me is that there is only one value per object.

Comment: I have to say that tutorial doesn't look particularly clear or well written and it's not really sufficient for what you're trying to do. You need to use a time format on the x axis. Follow something like http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/format-date-time-axis-with-specified.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a  few changes to specify the property within your object you want the data to be based on, in your case "value".

First get the max Y.

```
maxY = d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
});
```

You want to modify this line from the tutorial and replace d3.max(data) with maxY.

```
y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0 + margin, h - margin])
```

Then you'll need to modify this code to specify your values as well

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
   .y(function(d) { return -1 * y(d.value); })
```